# How can I get to the blobstore in the new Google Cloud Console?

Tags: google-app-engine

is there a way to access the blobstore in the new console?

I couldn't find one, nor did I find a way to return to the old console

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While most likely this is still not implemented yet, but you can still access the old **Blob Viewer** from this link:

```
https://appengine.google.com/blobstore/explorer?&app_id=s~<APPLICATION_ID>
```

Comment: Unless you know if this is implement anywhere by now..? I'd say it's pretty weird this does not exist in the currently supported console.

Comment: They want to phase out the Blobstore for the new Cloud Storage. I still use the Blobstore: very easy to use. Until there is a tutorial on how to add Images and Videos to the Cloud Storage and how to serve them back, I am staying with the Blobstore.

Comment: Thanks, man! this looks interesting. I will take a look at the docs that comes with it. Thanks. +1

Comment: @learner the docs are a bit outdated.. but feel free to open an issue if you are lost :)

Answer (score 2):

The Blobstore UI is now accessible from the Developer Console at this link:

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/blobstore?project=<APPLICATION_ID>
```

Or just browse to App Engine -> Blobstore.