# how to migrate google blobstore chunk files to azure blob store

Tags: google-app-engine, azure, azure-blob-storage, blobstore

I am migrating my google app engine project to windows azure app platform.Please help me to migrate the all google app engine blobstore files to Azure blobstore.
I have one solution with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264428/how-to-transfer-file-to-azure-blob-storage-in-chunks-without-writing-to-file-usi).But I am not much aware of Python,Please help me if it is possible with javascript,java or any tool.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this (if you are not working with a huge amount of data) would be to download the google app engine blobstore files to a local drive, and then upload them using a tool like Azure Storage Explorer (http://storageexplorer.com/). Azure Storage Explorer lets you upload a directory through the user interface. Or you can use the AzCopy command-line interface to upload local files to Blob storage (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/).

For downloading google blobstore files, you may be able to use a tool or interface like the ones described here: [How can I get to the blobstore in the new Google Cloud Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26345775/how-can-i-get-to-the-blobstore-in-the-new-google-cloud-console)

If you have a very large amount of data, then you may need a different option. For uploading very large amounts of data to Azure Blob storage, you can use the Import/Export service, and send Microsoft a drive containing your data (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-import-export-service/).